# Doesn't remove the right item in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My state cart value (shirtsList) is a separate file with an array of T-shirt objects. What I'm trying to do is delete an item from the array by clicking on the REMOVE button that is in the itemOptions.js component file. My remove handler is handleRemoveItem, as you can see in the App.js file.

App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Item from './Components/item';
import ItemProperties from './Components/itemProperties';
import { shirtsList } from './shirtsList';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quantity: [],
      totalItems: 0,
      size: ['S', 'M', 'L'],
      color: ['red', 'blue', 'black'],
      cart: shirtsList
    }
  }

  handleRemoveItem = (shirt) => {
    console.log(shirt)
    let index = this.state.cart.filter((item) => {
      return shirt !== item
    })
    this.setState({cart: index})
  }


  render() {
    this.setState.quantity = shirtsList.map((shirt, i) => {
      return ( 
        this.state.quantity.push({amount: shirtsList[i].quantity})
      ) 
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="itemInTheCart">

        {
          this.state.cart.map((shirt, i) => {
          return ( 
            <Item 
              onClick={(e) => this.handleRemoveItem(shirt)}
            />
            ) 
          })
        }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

item.js component file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ItemOptions from './itemOptions';

const item = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="item">
            <ItemOptions onClick={props.onClick}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default item;
```

itemOptions.js component file:

```
import React from 'react';

const itemOptions = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="itemOptions">
            <p className="itemOptions__remove" onClick={props.onClick}>X REMOVE |&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default itemOptions;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `setState` inside of your `render` function.

Comment: @bradcush Note that `this.setState.quantity = ...` does not call `setState()`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line starting `this.setState.quantity = ...`? There are many things wrong with this, but I can't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to put the quantity of each T-shirt in the state.

Comment: My main problem as I wrote in the description is to make the REMOVE button work by deleting the right item from the list.

Comment: There are so many mistakes in your App.js. You should never do setState in component render and the way you are doing push is not correct. Never recommend mutating state directly without setState. Also you should understand how to do modify state in ReactJS, what you are doing doesn’t make sense

Comment: Show us what shirt contains in handleRemoveItem and this.state.cart. Without knowing that innerData I don’t think we can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments (and now previously provided answer by @Think-Twice) what you are trying to with `this.setState.quantity = shirtsList.ma...` in your render method is wrong. So avoid doing something like that. But, this part seems not related to removing the items from the cart? So, apart from this part of your code, actually it works.

I've changed the code slightly.

- Removed the bad part.
- Pass the `shirt` to the `Item` component then to `ItemOptions` component. Also, this second component is actually not necessary. You are not doing anything in `Item` component here. Just passing the props.
- I triggered the remove function in `ItemOptions` component, so no need to pass anything in the parent one by invoking the function. We have the `shirt` here, so used it.
- In the remove function, instead of comparing objects, I've used `id`s. So, stick to this strategy if possible.
- Added some unnecessary style.

```js
const shirtsList = [
  { id: 1, color: "red", size: "S", quantity: 10 },
  { id: 2, color: "blue", size: "M", quantity: 20 },
  { id: 3, color: "yellow", size: "L", quantity: 30 },
  { id: 4, color: "red", size: "S", quantity: 40 },
  { id: 5, color: "blue", size: "M", quantity: 50 },
]

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quantity: [],
      totalItems: 0,
      size: ['S', 'M', 'L'],
      color: ['red', 'blue', 'black'],
      cart: shirtsList
    }
  }

  handleRemoveItem = (shirt) => {
    const newCart = this.state.cart.filter((item) => {
      return shirt.id !== item.id
    })
    this.setState({cart: newCart})
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="itemInTheCart">
        {
          this.state.cart.map((shirt, i) => {
          return ( 
            <Item
              key={shirt.id}
              onClick={this.handleRemoveItem}
              shirt={shirt}
            />
            ) 
          })
        }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Item = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="item">
      <ItemOptions shirt={props.shirt} onClick={props.onClick} />
      {/* or you can use 
      <ItemOptions {...props} />
      */}
    </div>
  );
}

const ItemOptions = (props) => {
  const handleClick = () => props.onClick( props.shirt );
  return (
    <div className="itemOptions" style={{background: `${props.shirt.color}`}}>
      <p>ID: {props.shirt.id}&nbsp;
      Size: {props.shirt.size}&nbsp;
      Quantity: {props.shirt.quantity}&nbsp;
      Color: {props.shirt.color}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>X REMOVE</button>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: how does index number can be set to cart when the cart contains array of objects? I am talking about the setState in handleRemoveItem event handler

Comment: Actually, it is not an actual index here :) OP named it like that. I really don't know why. But, it is a simple filter operation, returning a new array where the removed item is not in. So, I've updated the code with the name `newCart` :)

Comment: Ah also, `cart` is set to `shirtLists` in the state right away in the constructor. So, in the beginning it is the `shirtLists` itself. An array of objects as I understood. It is very hard to understand the OP's intention here.

Comment: Yeah I just looked at constructor and the index name. Didn’t realise that the naming is incorrect but the filter is returning a filtered cart. My bad. Thanks :)

Comment: Nobody's bad :) OP's mind is a little bit confused. I hope s/he finds the right way on this journey :)

Comment: Yeah. BTW what this OP stands for?

Comment: OP = "Original Poster" :) Or sometimes it can be "Original Post" I guess. https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Op

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks 

Answer (score 4):

There are so many mistakes that you are doing in App.js

1. Never do setState in render.
2. The way you are doing setState isn’t correct
3. Never mutate state directly. You must use setState to modify state value
4. Try to keep your render as much as clean by availing react provided life cycle methods.
5. The way your pushing items to an array is not recommended because you are mutating directly

The proper way of pushing into an array using setState in React would be something like below

```
  render() {
       shirtsList.map((shirt, i) => {
            let obj = {};
            obj.amount = shirt.quantity;
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                 quantity: [...prevState.quantity, obj]
            }));
        })
   }
```